# Present new view controller underneath current view controller

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a new view controller that comes in via the presenting view controller being dismissed and having the presented view controller 'already' be behind the presenting one, much in the same way a modal view controller is presented/dismissed.

Is there a way to achieve this by just presenting the view controller, or do I somehow have to present the view controller before hand and then hide it underneath and then dismiss the presenting view controller?

Comment: How is the current view controller presented? Modally? In a nav controller? As a child of something else?

Comment: does my answer help? do you have any more questions? :) @micnguyen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this indeed by "hiding" your second view controller underneath the first view controller that you want to display. `UINavigationController` gives you everything you need for this for free.

Use the following (pseudo-)code from the view controller where you are showing the modal view:

```
FirstVC *first = [[FirstVC alloc] init]; // this VC is shown first
SecondVC *second = [[FirstVC alloc] init]; // this VC that hides beneath the other

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];
[nav pushViewController:first animated:NO];

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, whenever you want to dismiss the first view controller, you can call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Note that you still will have to dismiss the modal view then.

Comment: Thanks nburk - that's exactly what I wanted. I wasn't sure if I pushed a view controller non-animated, whether or not it would still do a really junky-animation but this is great, I just have to give it a custom navigation controller animation controller. Cheers mate.